# Convert Excel code into C#

Tags: c#, excel, vba

I have VBA in Excel which calculates some values. Now I have to implement the technique there into C#. I tried to understand the VBA but could not 'get' it as I haven't done work much in Excel.

Can any expert help me convert the following into C#?

```vb
Sub SingleLN()
'
' SingleLN Macro
'

k = 8
j = 35

'Reset Trial number and time
Cells(4, j + 12).Value = ""
Cells(5, j + 12).Value = ""
Cells(6, j + 12).Value = ""


Cells(5, j + 12).Value = Now
Trials = Cells(4, j + 9).Value
For i = 1 To Trials
Cells(4, j + 12).Value = i

    SolverReset


            Cells(4, 5).Value = (18 - 0.5) * Rnd + 0.5
            Cells(5, 5).Value = (4 - 0) * Rnd + 0

            Cells(k + i, j + 1).Value = Cells(4, 5).Value
            Cells(k + i, j + 2).Value = Cells(5, 5).Value

            Cells(k + i, j + 9).Value = Cells(2, 21).Value
            Cells(k + i, j + 10).Value = i


    SolverOk SetCell:="$U$2", MaxMinVal:=1, ValueOf:="0", ByChange:= _
        "$E$3:$E$5,$G$4:$G$5"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$3", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$3", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$4", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$4", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$5", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$5", Relation:=3, FormulaText:="0"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$E$3", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverAdd CellRef:="$G$3", Relation:=1, FormulaText:="1"
    SolverOptions MaxTime:=100, Iterations:=1000, Precision:=0.000001, AssumeLinear _
        :=False, StepThru:=False, Estimates:=1, Derivatives:=1, SearchOption:=1, _
        IntTolerance:=5, Scaling:=False, Convergence:=0.0001, AssumeNonNeg:=True
    SolverSolve UserFinish:=True
    SolverFinish KeepFinal:=1

    Result = Application.Run("Solver.xlam!SolverSolve", True)

  ' finish the analysis
    Application.Run "Solver.xlam!SolverFinish"


        Cells(k + i, j + 12).Value = Cells(4, 5).Value
        Cells(k + i, j + 13).Value = Cells(5, 5).Value

        Cells(k + i, j + 20).Value = Cells(2, 21).Value
        Cells(k + i, j + 21).Value = Cells(5, 14).Value

        ' report on success of analysis
            'If Result = 0 Then
            'Cells(k + i, j + 22).Value = "SOLUTION FOUND, optimality and constraints satisfied"

            'ElseIf Result = 1 Then
            'Cells(k + i, j + 22).Value = "SOLUTION FOUND, converged, constraints satisfied"

            'ElseIf Result = 2 Then
            'Cells(k + i, j + 22).Value = "SOLUTION FOUND, Cannot improve, constraints satisfied"

            'ElseIf Result = 3 Then
            'Cells(k + i, j + 22).Value = "SOLUTION FOUND, Stopped at maximum iterations"

            'Else
              ' Result = 4, Solver did not converge
              ' Result = 5, No feasible solution
            'Cells(k + i, j + 22).Value = "NO SOLUTION"
            'End If
       Cells(k + i, j + 22).Value = Result
    Next i
Cells(6, j + 12).Value = Now
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Nothing has been declared, so all your variables are type `variant`

VBA:

```vb
k = 8
j = 35
...
Trials = Cells(4, j + 9).Value
```

C#:

```
var k;
var j;
var Trials;

// example, the cells methods will need to be fully qualified properly.
k = 8;
j = 35;
Trials = sh.Cells[4, j + 9].Value2;
```

2. `SolverReset`, `SolverOk` and `SolverAdd` appear to be routines in an add-in that you haven't provided the code for. So not much to do there...
3. `For i = 1 To Trials` in C# is `for(int i = 1; i <= Trials; i++)`

Everything else is fairly standard.

Comment: SolverReset, SolverOk and SolverAdd are referred from Solver Add-in. you have to add it manually From File > Options > Add-Ins

Comment: I know, but the point is I'm not going away to research those procedures for you - if you want help with some code then you have to provide that code. Ideally, you should show what you have tried to convert yourself and _then_ ask for help when you run into issues. I'm just "throwing you a bone" here.